# IE8 not refreshing popup window

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

IE 8 is not refreshing a popup window that shows an image with some basic javascript manipulator.

I am trying to investigate issues with IE 8 and ASP.net 3.5 but I am not having much luck with that research.

So what I am doing?

I have a tab container(Ajax control toolkit) that holds a gridview that when you select it, it will show a popup with the selected image. I am passing the image location through a Session variable. In firefox 3.5 it always displays the different images.

Here is the code being inserted into the page for javascript:

```
Dim javatext As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
Session("ImageLoc") = Path
javatext.Append("<script>window.open('" & "ImageViewer.aspx" & "',null,'left=400,")
javatext.Append(" top=100,height=600px, width=600px, status=no, resizable= yes, scrollbars= yes,")
javatext.Append("toolbar= no,location= no, menubar= no');</script>")

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "showTreatMedia", javatext.ToString())
```

This code with different paths is in two command buttons in the grid view. And the path differs depending on if the user wants a compressed format or the original format. Checking the code it enters the first time but not the second.

Page load of the showing image window:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsNothing(Session("ImageLoc")) Then
            imgPic.ImageUrl = Session("ImageLoc")
        End If
End Sub
```

Also the site is running in IE7 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what happened was that I was using the same URL all the time. I added this code:

```
Dim rand As New Random
Dim numvalue As Integer = rand.Next(0, 2000)
Session("ImageLoc") = objMedia.PathFull
javatext.Append("<script>window.open('" & "ImageViewer.aspx?something=" & numvalue & "',null,'left=400,")
javatext.Append(" top=100,height=600px, width=600px, status=no, resizable= yes, scrollbars= yes,")
javatext.Append("toolbar= no,location= no, menubar= no');</script>")

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "showTreatMedia", javatext.ToString())
```

And now it changes the picture every time and picks up the new path. So the holding the path of the image in the session variable was a mistake. And it seems IE8 needs for the path to change to refresh the popup window.

Hope this can help other people.

Comment: It's likely that the real problem is that your ImageViewer.aspx page wasn't sending caching headers that would prohibit IE from reusing the previously cached version of the page. Learn more here: www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf